# Mongo shell user not defined

Tags: mongodb

I'm tryin to login as user "overnet" on db "overnet" in mongodb;

I'm logged in the mongo shell as follow;

```
mongo -u root -p (password) --authenticationDatabase admin
```

and then typed:

```
use overnet
switched to db overnet

show users
{
  "_id" : "overnet.overnet",
  "user" : "overnet",
  "db" : "overnet",
  "roles" : [
    {
      "role" : "readWrite",
      "db" : "overnet"
    },
    {
      "role" : "dbOwner",
      "db" : "overnet"
    }
  ]
}
> db.auth(overnet, password)
2014-12-07T08:05:43.907+0100 ReferenceError: overnet is not defined
```

how can it say that "overnet" is not defined???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`overnet` not defined because not quoted. Try the following: `db.auth("overnet", password)`